# Generate an Angular 5 component at run time from string

Tags: angular, dynamic, compilation, render, angular5

I am looking for a way to display a component dynamically from a string.

For Example, Existing Component:

```
<app-header></app-header
```

I need to include this in another component. I would love to do something like:

TS:

`@ViewChild('componentHost1', { read: ViewContainerRef }) componentHost1: ViewContainerRef;`

`const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory('<app-header></app-header>');
this.componentHost1.clear();
this.componentHost1.createComponent(componentFactory);`

HTML:

`<ng-template #componentHost1></ng-template>`

I do not know the component before it is passed so I cannot use the actual component only a string of the component usage.

Is there a way to render/compile this from a string to use in another component?

Or even better it would be awesome to just do:

`<div [innerHtml]="'<app-header></app-header>'"></div>`

Comment: Can you not use `ng-content` in your component?

Comment: Ng-content does not help when what you are trying to transclude is a string of another component `'<app-header></app-header>'`. I need a way to convert a string to a real component.